# Using mySQLi reserved words and functions - Security

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am not experienced with SQLi and am learning it as I go but I wanted to ask this question because I am learning about SQL injection attacks.

I have used the mySQLi reserved words and functions to process my queries and to make my databases function.

After reading about these attacks and how to protect myself I wondered if I should ever use this library as I have not seen anybody else use it. Non of my lecturers use it and if it is bad practice to use it, can I ask why?

This is a sample of my code below. As you can see I use reserved words and functions like "mysqli_num_rows(), mysqli_free_result() and mysqli_close(). Is this library bad practice and why? Thank you

```
<?php
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }


# Run the query, store result in a string and store number of rows returned 
$result= mysqli_query($con,"select * from gameRecords") or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));
//echo $result;

// Return the number of rows in result set
$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($rowcount !=0)
    {
        echo("Result set has $rowcount rows.<br>");
        /* fetch associative array*/
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            ?>
            <tr><td>
            <?php
            echo $row["gameNo"]."</td>"."<td>";
            echo $row["oppTeam"]."</td>"."<td>";
            echo $row["date"]."</td>"."<td>";
            echo $row["location"]."</td>"."<td>";
            echo $row["result"]."</td>"."<td>";
            echo $row["ko"]."</td>"."<td>";
            echo $row["score"]."</td>"."<td>";
            echo $row["fhInfo"]."</td>"."<td>";
            echo $row["shInfo"]."</td>"."<td>";


            ?>
            </td>
            </tr>

            <?php
        }
        //free result set 
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    }

# Closes the database
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "mysqli reserved words"?

Comment: You should use mysqli or PDO. The mysql library was deprecated years ago, and it has been removed completely in PHP 7.

Comment: I am using mysqli instead of PDO. I'm just wondering if there is a negative as I don't see anyone use it.

Comment: Unfortunately, lots of lecturers and tutorials have not kept up with the times, and they still teach the same library they've been using for a decade.

Comment: There's no negative, it's the right thing to do. If you post code here using the `mysql` library you'll get lots of people complaining that you need to update your code.

Comment: Have you looked at the online documentation of the `mysql` functions? They all start with a big warning that those functions should no longer be used. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: @Barmar OP is using mysqli and NOT mysql. mysqli_ are deprecated as php 7 but mysqli_ is still valid and safe to use.

Comment: @LouisLoudogTrottier I know that. His question is whether that's what he should be doing, because his teacher and colleagues are still using `mysql`.  I explained why they're wrong and he's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st, you are using mysqli, that is correct and secure (when used in a secured way). Not to mix up with mysql (without the 'i') that is deprecated.

those 'reserved' word you are talking about are functions. They are there to be used. You are using it in a procedural way, that is again a matter of taste and how you build stuff more than a security issue.

there is nothing wrong with your code. As far as your query goes.

```
$result= mysqli_query($con,"select * from gameRecords");
```

BUT if you where to use inputs to build you query you NEED to turn to prepared statements. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Theres alot of documentation about prepared statement. I am using mysqli also and most people assume that you are using PDO when you talk about statement so be carefull when looking for answers and the syntax is similar but not identical.

Comment: Thanks. I need to get my statements prepared for input so thanks for the link too.